# Keep navigation controller through storyboard of application

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

What happens with navigation controller when pushing view controller modally? 
I mean when I do transition from one controller to another with "Push" method, destination controller has link to same navigation controller as source controller, but when I make "Push modally" transition, destination controller viewed modally has not link to navigation controller.

Comment: in here you need to add another one Navigationcontroller before modally

Comment: if you dismiss the current naviation also dismiss and your  initial navigation is available

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. Your navigation controller is still there. If you're worried about the navigation bar not being visible, the reason is that your current VC was presented by the top VC on your navigation controller's stack. If you want your navigation bar back, you'll need to dismiss the modally presented vc (dismissViewController(animated : Bool), is the method for that).